# Decision tree implementation issue in apache spark with java

Tags: java, machine-learning, bigdata, apache-spark, decision-tree

I'm trying to implement simple demo for decision tree classifier using java and apache spark 1.0.0 version. I base on http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/mllib-decision-tree.html. So far I've wrote code listed below.

in line with following code I get error:

```
org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.impurity.Impurity impurity = new org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.impurity.Entropy();
```

Type mismatch: cannot convert from Entropy to Impurity.
It's strange for me, while class Entropy implements Impurity interface:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/impurity/Entropy.html

I'm looking answer for question why I can't make this assignment?

```
package decisionTree;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.DecisionTree;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.configuration.Algo;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.configuration.Strategy;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.impurity.Gini;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.impurity.Impurity;

import scala.Enumeration.Value;

public final class DecisionTreeDemo {

    static class ParsePoint implements Function<String, LabeledPoint> {
        private static final Pattern COMMA = Pattern.compile(",");
        private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");

        @Override
        public LabeledPoint call(String line) {
            String[] parts = COMMA.split(line);
            double y = Double.parseDouble(parts[0]);
            String[] tok = SPACE.split(parts[1]);
            double[] x = new double[tok.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < tok.length; ++i) {
                x[i] = Double.parseDouble(tok[i]);
            }
            return new LabeledPoint(y, Vectors.dense(x));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage:DecisionTreeDemo <file>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext("local[4]", "Log Analizer",
                System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"),
                JavaSparkContext.jarOfClass(DecisionTreeDemo.class));

        JavaRDD<String> lines = ctx.textFile(args[0]);
        JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> points = lines.map(new ParsePoint()).cache();

        int iterations = 100;

        int maxBins = 2;
        int maxMemory = 512;
        int maxDepth = 1;

        org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.impurity.Impurity impurity = new org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.impurity.Entropy();

        Strategy strategy = new Strategy(Algo.Classification(), impurity, maxDepth,
                maxBins, null, null, maxMemory);

        ctx.stop();
    }
}
```

@samthebest if I remove impurity variable and change to following form:

```
Strategy strategy = new Strategy(Algo.Classification(), new org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.impurity.Entropy(), maxDepth, maxBins, null, null, maxMemory);
```

error changed to: The constructor Entropy() is undefined.

[edited]
I found I think proper invocation of method (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2197):

```
Strategy strategy = new Strategy(Algo.Classification(), new Impurity() {
@Override
public double calculate(double arg0, double arg1, double arg2)
{ return Gini.calculate(arg0, arg1, arg2); }

@Override
public double calculate(double arg0, double arg1)
{ return Gini.calculate(arg0, arg1); }

}, 5, 100, QuantileStrategy.Sort(), null, 256);
```

Unfortunately I run into bug :(

Comment: Odd. Try just inlining it rather than assigning to a variable. After all you only use the variable once.  Also really recommend using Scala rather than the Java API, you can do that whole thing in literally a couple of lines and it will be much easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Java solution for Bug 2197 is available now, through [this pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/1740):

> Other improvements to Decision Trees for easy-of-use with Java:
>   * impurity classes: Added instance() methods to help with Java interface.
>   * Strategy: Added Java-friendly constructor
>   --> Note: I removed quantileCalculationStrategy from the Java-friendly  constructor since (a) it is a special class and (b) there is only 1
>   option  currently.  I suspect we will redo the API before the other
>   options are  included.

You can see a full example, that is going ahead your problem using intance() method of Gini impurity [here](https://github.com/jkbradley/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/test/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/JavaDecisionTreeSuite.java)

```
Strategy strategy = new Strategy(Algo.Classification(), Gini.instance(), maxDepth, numClasses,maxBins, categoricalFeaturesInfo);
DecisionTreeModel model = DecisionTree$.MODULE$.train(rdd.rdd(), strategy);
```